# Set font size for web part zone

Tags: 2010, branding, content-editor-web-part, web-part-zone

I have SP2010 Web Part Page with several Content Editor web parts in the 'body' Web Part Zone.
I would like to set the typeface and point size of the titles displayed in the web part chrome. It seems like this is something I should be doing as a property of the zone, but I don't see any way to do that in the UI. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to set font properties for the webpart titles? If so you can just create a CSS style on your page for the **ms-WPTitle** class and embed it right into the page:

```
<style>
    .ms-WPTitle 
    {
        FONT-FAMILY: arial; 
        FONT-SIZE: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Note that this will affect the title of every web part on the page, not those only inside the 'body' zone. If the you need to isolate only web parts in that specific zone, you'd need to grab the HTML id of the zone div/cell and append that as `#idofzone .ms-WPTitle`.